# How do I search for computers and devices on my network that don't belong to my domain?

Tags: powershell

I'm a network admin who's trying to automate some things using PowerShell and one task I'm trying to automate is the addition of computers to my domain, and the renaming of said computers. My company frequently gets new computers and I want to avoid having to go through all the menus. I have a script that can do this, but I want to be able to query computers and devices not on my domain so I can easily add them. I know about Env:Userdomain, but I don't know how I can query computers if they're not joined to AD. Is there any way I can do this in PS?

Additionally, I would like to avoid having to re-enter my credentials for every computer I want to join to the domain. Is there a way to store my username and password and have the operations continue automatically after entering my credentials once?

Comment: Keep your DHCP pool small, assign computers a static IP when they're setup on the domain, and scan your DHCP pool range. Anything there should be a non-domain joined machine.

Comment: You're misunderstanding my question. I am looking for devices on the network but not part of our Active Directory system.

Comment: theMadTech was providing an approach to mitigate this issue now and in the future. I do not believe he misunderstood. Your question however is really broad as far as solutions go. If the machines are not controlled then who is to say the firewall states of these machines. You are asking two questions 1. How to find non domain computers and then 2. how to remotely add them to the domain. The former might be easier if you had network inventory software that can scan ips with credential sets if you are using the same password for local admin. Can you use DHCP to see computers with different names

Comment: Well to add them to the domain I will have physical access to them to enable remoting.

Also, the proposed solution is really not possible at this point. There is far too much infrastructure in place as it is. I didn't set this up myself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the first part of your question when you say query computers. You may be able to use the Add-Computer cmdlet inside Invoke-Command cmdlet to remotely add machines to the domain. Never tried it.

For your credential question, many powershell commands have a -Credential parameter. You can collect your creds once and pass it to a looping script something like:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
For Each ($i in $collection)
{
   My-Cmdlet -Credential $creds
}
```

Another option is to create a [PSCredentials](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/) object but you got to store your creds in plain text

Comment: What I mean by that is I want to search for those computers that are on the network but outside the domain.

The second portion is very helpful though. Thank you.

Comment: Have they been registered in DNS?

Comment: No. The point is to make the process of adding new computers to the domain when my organization gets them as easy and quick as possible.

Comment: Also, the credentials foreach would have to be wrapped in another foreach as I'm already going through an array of computer names. I think that might screw with the logic. 

This, and will what you proposed handle both username and password?